# Let mods sort the timeline from oldest to newest

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, timeline

For some time, moderators have had a "timeline" view into the history of questions.

[image: History view]

At the moment, it is always sorted descending (newest to oldest. However, I usually look at it specifically *because* I want to see what happened in the order it happened. Please either change the sort order, or at least allow us to change it while looking at it.

Comment: I don't mind if it's a toggle, but I appreciate the consistency of the current layout with the revision history, activity tab, and probably other things that I can't think of right now.

Comment: That’s a much nicer view than [the publicly-accessible timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/245819/timeline) (which I should note *does* have the ability to change the ordering).